# Pass data after http.post to component

Tags: angular, http, observable, form-data

I'm working on a small web application.
Now I try to implement a file upload function. Everything is working well. I can upload, save it on the server and also receive the file path.

The thing i now struggle with, is how to pass the path back to the component.

I tried several solutions, but I'm not sure what do use and also how do modifiy the code.

Should I use async, await or an Eventemitter, Observable, etc...?

And how do use them correctly that I receive the path in the component, I know I have do wait for the service function do finish.

**The function in the service**

```
  // Images hochladen
  uploadImage(postData: FormData): string{
    this.http.post('https://10.0.0.3:3000/api/upload/image', postData)
    .subscribe((responseData) => {
      this.imgPath = responseData['path'];
      console.log(this.imgPath)
    });
    return this.imgPath;
  };
```

**And in the component**

```
const imgPath = this.projectsService.uploadImage(dataFile);
console.log(imgPath);
```

Thanks for every help :-)

Best regards

Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main alternatives:

### Use promises:

Service:

```
async uploadImage(postData: FormData): Promise<string> {
    const promise = this.http.post('https://10.0.0.3:3000/api/upload/image', postData).toPromise();
    return (await promise)['path'];
  };
```

Component:

```
async something() {
  const imgPath = await this.projectsService.uploadImage(dataFile);
  console.log(imgPath);
}
```

### Use observables:

Service:

```
uploadImage(postData: FormData): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post('https://10.0.0.3:3000/api/upload/image', postData)
               .pipe(last(),map(r => r['path']));
  };
```

Component:

```
something() {
  this.projectsService.uploadImage(dataFile).subscribe(imgPath => {
     console.log(imgPath);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Joel. Great thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Please choose Observables 